# Cannot see Git repository in cPanel Git™ Version Control module

Tags: git, deployment, cpanel

I cannot see any repositories in the cPanel Git™ Version Control module, even though the files were successfully pulled from the remote and are visible in the file system.

I am trying to setup deployments via cPanel using cPanel's Git deployment system (see for example: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git).

After I encountered errors cloning the remote repository from GitHub using SSH, I found that it is a GitHub problem that their system prefers an HTTPS connection rather than SSH:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey
I connected this way, and it worked (e.g., I did not get the permission denied error) (see code)

But, apparently because I used HTTPS rather than SSH, I cannot use the visual interface in this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rkxyd1f88jv4ge/cPanel%20-%20Git%E2%84%A2%20Version%20Control%202019-06-18%2010-39-33.png?dl=0

So, my question is, how do I now get the repository to appear in the interface, so that I can use the visual interface, and NOT USE terminal, to manage deployments?

username@host ~]# ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/lwtogithub.pub

Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/lwtogithub.pub:
[username@host ~]# git clone https://github.com/username/forwardjump-genesis-child.git
Cloning into 'forwardjump-genesis-child'...
Username for 'https://github.com': username
Password for 'https://username@github.com':
remote: Enumerating objects: 762, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (762/762), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (267/267), done.
remote: Total 762 (delta 480), reused 758 (delta 479), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (762/762), 771.86 KiB | 8.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (480/480), done.
[username@host ~]#

I would like the repository to appear in the cPanel Git™ Version Control module as in this screenshot:

https://blog.cpanel.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/image2018-3-23_9-48-58.png

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to add the repository but selecting create, and then unchecking the clone button on the next page... use the repositories path and this will add the repository to the listings